# Change the weather icons of the Yahoo weather API

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, weather, weather-api

Does anyone know how to change the weather logo of the **yahoo weather API** ?, i tried to change the classes but it doesn't work.

For example, some color logos like [this](https://codepen.io/r00bal/pen/jrpgXA) ,and Im based on [this](https://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/xklfq) Codepen sample

**HTML** code:

```
<div id="weather"></div>
```

**JS** code:

```
// v3.1.0
//Docs at http://simpleweatherjs.com
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: 'Austin, TX',
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.wind.direction+' '+weather.wind.speed+' '+weather.units.speed+'</li></ul>';

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS** code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'weather';
    src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.eot');
    src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/93/artill_clean_icons-webfont.svg#artill_clean_weather_iconsRg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to show your minimum code instead of links to codepen?

Comment: I did exactly the same thing, the same code

Comment: I added the code

Comment: It looks like you would have to replace the font.

Comment: yes, something like this, i have `font-family: weather` but idon't know how to find the others to change it